# Java Drop Down Lists

Tags: java, swing, awt

I have a drop down menu in java with 3 options and right next to it a run button. I am using eclipse in java and using apache wicket and html to run the program in a web browser. my question is, if i choose print data from the drop down and click on the run button it should print printing successful in the console. i have tried various methods, and its compiling but just not showing me the message that it should do according to the system.out.println statement.

```
Button b = new Button("Ausführen");
b.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    if(role.getValue().equals("Print Data")) {
      System.out.println("Printing successfull!");
    }
  }

});

form.add(b);
```

any ideas why?

Comment: Have you checked that role.getValue() is really equal to "Print Data"? (same case, no extra space etc.)

Comment: yes it is Print Data in both fields

Comment: 1) for better help sooner post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) 2) do you use pure `AWT` 3) or mixing `Swing` with `AWT`

Comment: I use awt. and i tried role.getValue() but it only gives me numerical positiion of the srting and not the actual string inside the dropdown itself.

Comment: did you implementing hard graphics code meaning OpenGL/CL CAD/CAM, if not then don't use AWT, use Swing and edit your question with an SSCCE, otherwise all comment or answers here will be shots to the dark